# Populating SignalR HubCallerContext.User from OWIN CookieAuthentication cookie

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an MVC5 web app using OWIN CookieAuthentication. When the user is successfully logged into the web app, a connection is made to a SignalR hub running in a console app, also configured with OWIN CookieAuthentication.

In the SignalR Startup I have specified GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication() because I want to get the HubCallerContext.User property hydrated with the ClaimsPrincipal sent from the web app. Inspecting the cookies available, I can see that the auth cookie is received successfully, but I can't figure out how to set up the OWIN configuration so that the readonly principal gets set from it.

I've seen related post suggestions, such as variations upon the below:

```
        var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
            }
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
```

But I cannot get these to have any effect, and in any case it seems to involve a lot of peripheral Identity framework related classes to be set up (which for now I've ported in from an MVC5 project template just to test with). I just want to hydrate the User property with the claims encrypted into the ticket, and then look up the identified user in my SignalR system however I see fit. How do I go about this?

**EDIT**: As a workaround I'm creating a separate "server cookie" at the time that I sign in the user in the web app. I binary serialize the ClaimsIdentity, encrypt that with AES, base 64 encode that and put that into the cookie. Then in my Hub class I have an on-demand User property which reads that cookie out and unpacks it. Not the ideal solution!

Comment: Stupid question, I know: you are bootstrapping the CookieAuthentication stuff before bootstrapping SignalR, aren't you?

Comment: If you mean app.MapSignalR() coming after app.UseCookieAuthentication(options), yes.

Comment: Doh, you know, I missed that bit about the self host part... :(  I'll remove my answer, sorry.

Comment: Have you managed to do this without the workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @Wasp you just saved my sanity, thank you!!! I was bootstrapping signalr before cookieauthentication and could not figure out why Authorization was failing on the hub (owin, mvc.net, signalr all hosted in same web app).